# Cut corners of Image using css

Tags: html, css

I want to cut image corners with transperant background. I have written following code.

```css
body{
  background-image:url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg');
}

.Image{
position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.Image img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.Image:before {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-top: 60px solid red;
    border-right: 60px solid transparent;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
}
.Image:after {
    position: absolute;
    content: "";
    border-bottom: 60px solid red;
    border-left: 60px solid transparent;
    bottom: -1px;
    right: -1px;
}

.blackBg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBg"></div>

<div class="Image">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
```

How can I cut image corners using css, also I don't want to use canvas or svg for this. I'd like to do it in pure CSS, are there any methods?

[image]

I want shape like this.

Comment: What do you mean by cutting corners, do you need rounded corners?

Comment: No I don't want rounded corner. Whatever I did written in snippet. In that I want transparency instead of red color.

Comment: Try border-radius:4px;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rotate the container 45 deg to the right, 
set overflow hidden on it.
and make the height bigger so that it won't clip the undesired corners.

Rotate the image -45deg so that it is horizontal again.

And you are done:

```css
body {
  background-image: url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg');
}
.Image {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-top: -100px;
}
.Image img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
.blackBg {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBg"></div>

<div class="Image">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
</div>
```

Answer (score 8):

Removed your before and after pseudo part and added clip-path styling.

```css
body{
  background-image:url('http://i.telegraph.co.uk/multimedia/archive/03589/Wellcome_Image_Awa_3589699k.jpg');
}

.Image{
  position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.Image img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 86%, 0% 20%);
  clip-path: polygon(20% 0%, 80% 0%, 100% 0%, 100% 80%, 80% 100%, 0% 100%, 0% 86%, 0% 20%);
}
}

.blackBg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBg"></div>

<div class="Image">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it compatible to all browser?

Comment: clip-path working on chrome only. Is there any other way to do this

Comment: Let me check or If this will not work with firefox then let me try an another solution.

Answer (score 1):

You will (hopefully) soon be able to use [border-corner-shape](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-4/#border-corner-shape) 
like this (now rounded corners may appear as fallback) and no need to use pseudo elements

```css
body{
  background:green;
}

.Image{
position:absolute;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
}

.Image img{
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  border-corner-shape: bevel;
  border-radius:30px 0 30px 0;
}

.blackBg{
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

```html
<div class="blackBg"></div>

<div class="Image">
  <img src="http://www.w3schools.com/css/img_fjords.jpg">
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can achive desire result through adding extra element or through css pseudo elements :before & :after**

```css
body{background:#fff;}
.img-ctnr{position:relative;}
.img{width:450px;height:300px;background:purple;}
.img-ctnr:before,.img-ctnr:after{
  content:'';position:absolute;display:block;
  width:100px;height:100px;
  background:#fff;
  transform:rotate(45deg);
}
.img-ctnr:before{top:-50px;left:-50px;}
.img-ctnr:after{top:250px;left:400px;}
```

```html
<div class="img-ctnr">
  <div class="img"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I am using background image behind this div that's why I can not use background:#fff; to after before

Answer (score 0):

Just do this in your css:

```
background: linear-gradient(135deg,rgb(72, 72, 245) 95% , rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 5%) ;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).